# Joomla! K2 - show extra fields

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I have a template overwrite for k2 items. In my item.php overwrite i try to get the extra fields for this item. But when i do this:

```
var_dump($this->item)
```

the output is this:

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 42
    [title] => ...
    [alias] => ...
    [catid] => 9
    [published] => 1
    [introtext] => ...
    [fulltext] => ...
    [video] => ...
    [gallery] => ...
    [extra_fields] => Array
        (
        )

    [extra_fields_search] => A B C D E F G H I  
    [created] => 2013-06-20 15:33:34
    [created_by] => 51
```

So - how i get the extra fields and not only all values without an seperator ? The $this->item->extra_fields is just an empty array ...

Btw: In the category settings "show extra fields" is on "show".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your output it seems like that there is no extra field group associated with the category of this item.

Comment: In "extra_field_search" you can the the options of this extra_field of this item. I dont know what i did, but now it works. I did nothing in the backend ... maybe a cache Problem at the first moment ? I dont know. Sorry for this.